# Differences in weeks between PHP and MySQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*), WEEK(date), YEAR(date) FROM myTable GROUP ON YEAR(date), WEEK(date)
```

Say it produces the following results

```
32 33 2012
43 34 2012
39 35 2012
17 36 2012
```

I now want to get all 39 records in week 35 of 2012.  I do not, however, wish to use `WEEK(date)=35 AND YEAR(date)=2012` in my WHERE clause as it does not utilize indexes.  Instead, I wish to find the boundaries and use conditionals.  I also do not want to use BETWEEN as rounding errors might occur.

I therefore try the following thinking all is good, but do not get 39 records.  Obviously MySQL and PHP deal differently with weeks. I see that MySQL WEEK() utilizes mode 0, 2, 4, and 6 that all return a week that starts with Sunday.  Ideally, I would have the one that is most commonly used by people, the most important thing is that it is the same as provided by DateTime.  How would I do so?  Thank you

```
$w=35;$y=2012;   //Given
$w=sprintf('%02d',$w);    //Make sure it is two digits
$date = new DateTime($y.'W'.$w);
$d1=$date->format('Y-m-d');
$date->add(new DateInterval('P1W'));
$d2=$date->format('Y-m-d');
$sql='SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE date >= ? AND date < ?';
```

Comment: Mysql handles the week count differntly based on the mode you pass it, [see Week(date, mode)](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week), you can also set this server-wide in the system variables.

Comment: Are you getting fewer than 39 records? Perhaps your WHERE condition should be `date <= ?`.

Comment: @fiz  I did see how WEEK() had different modes, but wasn't sure how this would help.

Comment: @BobDuell  I don't think so as that would include the first day of the next week.

Comment: @user1032531 You just need to figure out which mode PHP uses, and then set this in your mysql-server-variable, Mike Brant has already suggested the same as an answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are on the right track with regards to how MySQL works, having various modes for week-related functions that can produce different results. http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_week

It is my understanding the MySQL mode which is equivalent to PHP's date logic is mode 3, which is the ISO week date standard http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_week_date

This has weeks starting on Mondays and weeks numbered 1-53.

So you would need to use `WEEK(date_field, 3)` to get PHP compatible values.

As an alternate approach, one thing I have found handy in cases where you need the ability to flexibly query on different date ranges or aggregations (Q1- Q4, H1 - H2, etc.), or where you might need to utilize different weeks than PHP supports is to use a date helper table in MySQL (similar to what one may use as a date dimension table in a data warehouse, if you are familiar with that).  It can give you a convenient table to join against in order to look up date ranges.  Something like this should work:

http://databobjr.blogspot.com/2012/06/create-date-dimension-table-in-mysql.html

Comment: Ah ha, I was getting close.  I will check out mode 3!