# Why is MySQL current week less than PHP current week?

Tags: php, mysql, date

I'm curious to know why the MySQL current week number is 1 week less than the PHP current week number.

In the database, I am using the following command:

```
SELECT WEEK('2019-09-24')
```

Which outputs 38.

But in PHP, when I use the following:

```
<?php echo date('Y'); ?>
```

I get 39.

Is there any reason why I get different outputs, besides the fact they are 2 different technologies?

Comment: The issue here is that the week number depends on the convention/standard being used.  Note that a year has 365 (or 366) days, while 52 weeks is only 364 days.  This means that it is possible for January 1 to actually be part of the final week of the preceding year, depending on the scheme.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14470175/differences-in-weeks-between-php-and-mysql gives a lot more details - may be  a duplicate, but too much to read ATM.

Comment: Thanks, and upvotes to both of you.